# Aversion to already?

Tags: word-usage

A non-native translator into English, I use a native editor to check my translations.

My current editor has an absolute aversion to the word "already", deleting it every time. Here are the latest examples:

From the description of a feature film:
"The love affair between the two young women is sparked **already** on the bridge."

From the description of a neighbourhood that has often featured in films:
"In more recent films, the altered landscape has **already** taken on a romantic sheen..."

I can see that the sentence is fine without the adverb, but I fail to see why it should be deleted. It expresses the writers temporal perspective, and that would seem to be worth including in the translation – after all, it appears in the original.

Thanks in advance

Comment: I am with your editor. "Already" adds nothing to either sentence and I had to read the first one twice before I thought I understood it... I'm not sure I do.

Comment: I would use "already" when we know something happens later, but here we find it happens sooner than expected.  So if we do know the two young women fall in love, then your first example may be OK, showing it happened at an earlier time "on the bridge".

Comment: Best practice under the grueling circumstances is to accept the bias against *already* already, or to slip it in so the darn editor has something to redline. Either way, I'd expect the bias.

Comment: There's a lot of stigma around the word "alright" and to a lesser extent others like "already" and "altogether", with pedants thinking they're incorrect. See e.g. [M-W](https://www.merriam-webster.com/words-at-play/all-right-or-alright-which-is-correct). (But whether the word is needed is different to whether it's a valid word.)

Comment: The first sentence is definitely not an idiomatic usage of *already*. Even if you change its position and change the verb tense, you still have an odd one: ? *The love affair between the two young women was already sparked on the bridge.*

Answer (score 1):

Interesting question. Cambridge gives two meanings.

> [Cambridge A1](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/already)
>
> Already:
>
> before the present time:
> *-I asked him to come to the exhibition but he'd already seen it.
>
> -The concert had already begun by the time we arrived.
>
> -I've already told him.
>
> -As I have already mentioned, I doubt that we will be able to raise all the money we need.*

In these examples without context we may delete *already* with no significant loss of meaning, leaving plain statements.

Nevertheless, the context might justify keeping *already*. To modify these examples:

*-I asked him to come to the exhibition but he'd already seen it {contrary to my expectation that he had not}.

-The concert had already begun by the time we arrived {earlier than advertised or expected}.

-I've already told him {wasn’t he listening?}.

-As I have already mentioned, I doubt that we will be able to raise all the money we need {I did not expect to have to repeat myself – did you not understand what I said?}.*

This leads us to consider the second Cambridge definition:

> [Cambridge B1](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/already)
>
> Already:
> earlier than the time expected:
>
> *-Are you buying Christmas cards already? It's only September!
>
> -I've only eaten one course and I'm already full.
>
> -He was disappointed to find they'd already gone.
>
> -I've been waiting an hour already.
>
> -I knew a lot about the subject already, but her talk was interesting nevertheless.
>
> -The food is already on the table.
>
> -I think we've already had the best of the hot weather this summer.*

In these examples *already* is needed to indicate that there was a preceding expectation that is to be contrasted with actuality or has not been met in some way.

In conclusion, from this perspective, *already* is likely to be redundant in plain statements, may sometimes be retained if there is implied expectation within the context, and should be retained whenever explicit contrast of expectation and reality is needed.

Answer (score 0):

[Lexico](https://www.lexico.com/definition/already) [modified slightly] lists two quite different usages of the word *already*:

> **already** [adverb]
>
> - **(1) Before or by now or the time in question.**
>
> *Anna has suffered a great deal already.*
>
> *We already have early proofs back of the first batch of pages and they look good.*
>
> *My hair is already past my shoulders and my fringe has reached the tip of my nose.*
>
> *The snow whipped past my already red nose, and I looked around for a place for warmth.*
>
> *Support for a possible campaign to bring back the district has already gathered pace.*
>
> - **(1.1) As surprisingly [/worryingly/annoyingly; EA] soon or early as** **this.**
>
> *It was already past four o' clock.*
>
> ...
>
> - **(2) [North American] [informal] Used after a word or phrase to express** **impatience.**
>
> *Just stop already, no one feels sorry for you.*
>
> *If you like him so much, just tell him already instead of torturing yourself like this.*
>
> *He needs to just retire already.*
>
> *I thought this was fine; let's just hurry up already.*
>
> - Phrases
>   **enough already** [North American] [informal]
>
> Used to indicate unwillingness to tolerate any more of something
> undesirable.

The second usage here, as a marker of impatience, is doubtless the cause of the draconian ban. But the primary usage is fine (where not grossly redundant, which examples are rare) and fully acceptable to 99.9%+ of proficient Anglopohones. Indeed, it's vital where surprise at early completion needs to be conveyed:

"Have you finished your homework *already*!?" (The whole sentence is probably usually redundant semantically, but is idiomatic and has pragmatic value.)